# Why 'drawImage' does not accept parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas

In this line:

```js
context.drawImage(img, img.width, img.height)
```

got this error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '{ (image: CanvasImageSource, dx: number, dy: number): void; (image: CanvasImageSource, dx: number, dy: number, dw: number, dh: number): void; (image: CanvasImageSource, sx: number, sy: number, sw: number, sh: number, dx: number, dy: number, dw: number, dh: number): void; } | { ...; }' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.ts(2349)
```

```
(property) drawImage: {
    (image: Image | Canvas, dx: number, dy: number): void;
    (image: Image | Canvas, dx: number, dy: number, dw: number, dh: number): void;
    (image: Image | Canvas, sx: number, sy: number, sw: number, sh: number, dx: number, dy: number, dw: number, dh: number): void;
} | {
    ...;
}
```

And here is the method signature:

```js
const drawFrame = (
    context: CanvasRenderingContext2D | SKRSContext2D,
    positions: typeof startPositions,
    title: string,
    text: string,
    img: Image,
    locale?: string
) => {
```

parameters should fit. Then what is wrong?

using `napi-rs/canvas`

```js
import {
    createCanvas,
    GlobalFonts,
    Image,
    loadImage,
    SKRSContext2D,
} from '@napi-rs/canvas'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you use the generic `CanvasRenderingContext2D` definition, which expects for its `drawImage()` method a generic `CanvasImageSource` member which is made of the union `HTMLOrSVGImageElement | HTMLVideoElement | HTMLCanvasElement | ImageBitmap`.
The `Image` object that `loadImage()` returns doesn't match that union, it does miss some properties from `HTMLImageElement` that makes it no quite a valid value for `HTMLOrSVGImageElement`.

However the library you do use has already defined its own `SKRSContext2D` as being an extension of the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` interface, with its own `drawImage()` method that does accept `Image` (and `Canvas`) as source. So declaring your `context` parameter as `SKRSContext2D` only will make TS happy with your code:

```js
const drawFrame = (
    context: SKRSContext2D,
    positions: typeof startPositions,
    title: string,
    text: string,
    img: Image,
    locale?: string
) => {
```

[Simplified TS-playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwFB1XAxlApgQxlgYRwDsA3HAZwBoU0BJEHAcyxrTgBsIcATB51rVQBlANIAlYQQjF8ADxgAmACJIAvnABmUCCDgByAALEcYYAFooFAPToS5CvoDcSJOhkV4PKDgDuAMR8QLDgAXjgACiEMGXkYAC44MUlpWSwFFTY0UCZE-hYaAEowgD5EaPc0hQA6bz98rAicqjgABhbWwpc1V0rPOBywuD8cYHguXgaIgCJq62mutw94OzJKIcxcfCI1igiAZlb2uEPOlz6V2PT4cNWHapYYVLiZxR4FlzqAoMbKuJacl0gA).